# What does the console error 'Unable to clear quarantine' mean?

Tags: macos, installation

I'm making an OS X Installer package.  I download it from a build machine onto a test machine (10.5.8) and then run it.  In the console, the following message is immediately logged:

`kernel[0]: Finder[52646] Unable to clear quarantine '<package name>': 30`

From what I've read, Leopard sets a quarantine extended attribute on all downloaded files.  It's possible to use xattr to remove that flag, although that obviously doesn't apply to this situation, since a program can't un-quarantine itself.

I don't have a problem with the quarantine itself, or with Leopard popping up some dialog asking whether the user trusts the program.  But I would like to know why the quarantine could not be cleared, and whether there is a way to modify my installer or the scripts it runs to prevent that error from being logged.

Comment: Are you code signing any of this?

Comment: Some, but not all, of the binaries & scripts being installed are code-signed.

Comment: I don't see why an application could not unquaratine itself after it launched.

Answer (score 0):

Does the user on the test machine have administrative privileges? If the app is in a folder such as /Applications, you'll need them. If you can not change the user, try to download the app in his home folder.

Comment: The installer is on the desktop when it's run, so folder permissions aren't an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you downloaded it as a privileged user but you're running the installer as another user. Since the file is owned by the user that downloaded it, the user that wants to run it can only do so read-only. Check the file ownership and permissions to see if i'm right.

Comment: No, all admin. And no changes in privileges at all.

Comment: Likewise; same user (admin) downloaded and ran the package.

Answer (score 0):

- Try to copy from your build server using ditto (and pay attention on various switches that control the copy src and dst)
- check access rights on the share of your build server